# How to define radius while drawing sphere in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, geometry

I need to plot multiple sphere and I was using the example code from mathwork help as follows -

```
figure
[x,y,z] = sphere();
surf(x,y,z)  % sphere centered at origin
hold on
surf(x+3,y-2,z)  % sphere centered at (3,-2,0)
surf(x,y+1,z-3)  % sphere centered at (0,1,-3)
daspect([1 1 1])
```

I need the spheres to be different radius. How can I define radius for each of these spheres?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The helpfile for [`sphere`] (http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/techdoc/ref/sphere.html) says that it generates coordinates for a **unit sphere**, or a sphere of radius 1. To change coordinates for a sphere of radius 1 to a sphere of radius `r` you just multiply them by `r`:

```
[x,y,z] = sphere();
r = 5;
surf( r*x, r*y, r*z ) % sphere with radius 5 centred at (0,0,0)
```

Answer (score 2):

IMO, `surf()` is not user friendly at all. The code `surf(x+3,y-2,z)  % sphere centered at (3,-2,0)` is counter-intuitive (`surf(x-1,y+2,0)` is consistent with math).

Anyway, I'd recommend you use `ellipsoid()` instead. Since sphere is just a special case of ellipsoid, you can understand it easily and you don't have to deal with `surf()`, look at http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ellipsoid.html

A simple example:

```
r=5;
[x,y,z]=ellipsoid(1,2,3,r,r,r,20);
surf(x, y, z,'FaceColor','y', 'FaceAlpha', 0.2);
axis equal;
box on; xlabel('x-axis (m)'); ylabel('y-axis (m)'); zlabel('z-axis (m)');
```